# How to pass values from textbox to typescript file

Tags: typescript, angular2-services

please help me how can i pass my textbox values to typesccript

```
<div>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Email" />
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Password" />

        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" (click)="Validation()" />

    </div>
```

**Student.ts**
this is my class its having Email And password this call i used in studentController

```
  export class Validationclass {
            Email: string;
            Password: string;
        }
export class studentController {
        public val: Validationclass;

        Validation() {
            if (this.val.Email != null && this.val.Password != null) {
                alert('ok')
            }
            else
                alert("Emptr");

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the ngModel to the correct vars in your controller like this:

```
<div>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="val.Email" />
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="val.Password" />

      <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" (click)="Validation()" />

</div>
```

Make sure in your controller to initialize the ValidationClass like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  val = new Validationclass(); 
}
```